# MKPinAnnotation to Detailed view

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, swift, mkmapview

I have an object array from a PFQuery and then add MKPinAnnotations in my mapView with the following function:

```
func addAnnotation() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.objectArray.count; i++) {
        var location = object.objectForKey("location") as PFGeoPoint

        var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.setCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
        annotation.title = object.objectForKey("title") as NSString
        var priceFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

I have want to be able to click on the pin (or the information tab that shows when the pin is tapped) and segue to a detail view controller and pass the information associated with that pin or that index place in the Array...

I only need to know how to get the index number of the tapped pin so I can perform the segue...I've been stuck in this piece of code for the past 3 days and gave up and decided to ask the masters :P

Hope you can help me out please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class for your annotation where you can store additional information such as the array index:

```
class PinAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    private var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
            return coord
        }
    }

    var title: String = ""
    var subtitle: String = ""
    var index: Int = 0

    func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coord = newCoordinate
    }        
}
```

later in your code you can set the array index:

```
func addAnnotation() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.objectArray.count; i++) {
        var location = object.objectForKey("location") as PFGeoPoint

        var annotation = PinAnnotation()
        annotation.setCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
        annotation.title = object.objectForKey("title") as NSString
        annotation.index = i
        var priceFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

You have access to all the properties when you are working with the annotation object

Comment: It worked! It was such a simple solution but I couldn't think of it, I really appreciate it! Thanks!